# No Route Host on IOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, networking, udp, broadcast

I am developing IOS native application using Swift and I've done .udp broadcast. It was working well but after I updated my Iphone to IOS14, I started to get error when I try to broadcast, which says no route to host error code 65. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: this is simply badly written. Try and include more details, code samples and error messages.

Answer (score 1):

This is a new IOS "feature" where local network access is restricted and in particular broadcast and multicast require special approval from Apple.  See this for more information and a link to the entitlement request page:

https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=0oi77447